# What is need of specifying ref here in the below mongoose schema? What if we don't specify it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mern

```
 eventsAttended: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event' }]
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ref* is an option of mongoose to populate a field given a schema. So in case you omit ref in your "eventsAttended" field, you get only an objectID value, with no reference to any schema.

Docs here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-ref

Guide here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html